# Add regression layer to caffe

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, caffe, unsupervised-learning

I have implemented a smile detection system based on deep learning. The bottom layer is the output of the system and has 10 output according to the amount of the person's smile.
I want to convert these ten output with a numeric output in the range of 1 to 10 with a regression layer.
How can I do this in caffe?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert the 10 outputs you have to a single one you need an `"InnerProduct"` layer with 10 inputs and a single output. To train this layer you also need to add a loss layer suitable for regression on top of the 10 output layer you already have.
Such loss layers can be, e.g., [Euclidean loss layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cpp) or Ross Girshick's [smooth L1 loss layer](https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn/blob/fast-rcnn/src/caffe/layers/smooth_L1_loss_layer.cpp).

Comment: Can you elaborate on `smooth L1 loss layer` where it usually used?

Comment: @mrgloom you can read more about it in Girshick's [fast RCNN](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08083) paper.